# UTF-8 character encoding is not working on AWS Elasticbeanstalk Tomcat8 server for spring application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, tomcat, utf-8

UTF-8 character encoding is not working for my spring-based application after moving the server to AWS Elasticbeanstalk Tomcat 8.

I have referred steps from this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Character+Encoding#CharacterEncoding-Q3).

And below things, I have tried:

- Set `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` on your `<Connector>` in `server.xml`. References: HTTP Connector, AJP Connector.
- Change all your pages to include charset name using - `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` .
- Used `CharsetEncodingFilter` in `web.xml`.
- JVM Options to tomcat `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` and `-Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF8`

For AWS Elastibeanstalk tomcat JVM arguments,

```
{
            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions",
            "OptionName": "JVM Options",
            "Value": "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8"
}
```

In `web.xml` (This filter configuration is not changed. It was same in the old server as well.)

```xml
<filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In `.ebextensions/server.xml`

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
        ...
        <Service name="Catalina">
                ...
                <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                   redirectPort="8443" />

                <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3"
                   URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                   redirectPort="8443" />
                ...
        </Service>
        ...
</Server>
```

In `.ebextensions/httpd.conf`

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Ideally, it should work with these possible changes but I am getting junk characters for special characters for languages like Russian, Bulgarian, etc.

As a work-around as of now, I am using the following snippet wherever required in the application:

```java
public String convertToUTF(String value) {
        return StringUtils.isEmpty(value) ? value
                : new String(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Please suggest where I am missing any configuration here. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** Character encoding issue is coming after moving to AWS Elastibeanstalk Tomcat8 Linux Server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi do like this in the controller class.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")

public @ResponseBody DeclareExamMessage addComplaint(HttpServletRequest request) {
 try {

request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
//map the request object and pass it to sava method 
}

 }
```

---

After applying above changes if it is not working 
change your database **uft8 character set to utf8mb4**

and refer the below url

[Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have already had this DB handling for `utf8mb4` and set the character encoding for the request is handled by `CharacterEncodingFilter`. 

As I said, the application was working fine earlier, it is not working after migrating server to AWS. Please find the note at the end of issue description.

Comment: which is the environment do you have on AWS Linux or windows
if you have Linux 
Make sure to set the client and server character set as well. I have the following in my MySQL configuration file (/etc/my.cnf):

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Refer link- https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding the following to my `application.properties` resource

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.force=true
```